# How do I animate elements with different positions to move towards the same place/element?

Tags: javascript, css, css-animations

I am creating a shoe shop website for CV. I have multiple items rendered on home page, with option to add to cart. When user clicks on add to cart, I want to animate the element's picture to go towards the cart which is in header. I am able to start the animation using element's relative position, but I can't figure out how to get elements with different relative positions to end up going to the same place? For now I can get them to go up and away, but I want them to precisely to the CART. (for example, like in Humble bundle page).
I see people providing solutions by using jquery's animate, but I my app is react-based, so I'm trying to avoid jquery if possible.

```
@keyframes item-to-card-animation{
0%{ 
    position: relative;
    opacity:100%;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    transform: scale(1);
}

99%{
top:-1000px;
left:100px;
transform: scale(0.2);
z-index:100;
}
100%{
    opacity:0%;
}
```

}

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so if anyone stumbles upon this. I cloned an element in javascript, then put inline positions from javascript(since you can access it from there), then animated it using absolute positioning.

```
    const bodyRect = document.body.getBoundingClientRect();
    const elemRect = document.getElementById(this.state.itemToCart._id).getBoundingClientRect();
    const top = elemRect.top - bodyRect.top;
    const left = elemRect.left - bodyRect.left;
    let cloneItem =  document.getElementById(this.state.itemToCart._id).cloneNode(true);
    cloneItem.style.position = "absolute";
    cloneItem.style.top = top + "px";
    cloneItem.style.left = left + "px";
    cloneItem.classList.add('item-to-card-animation');
    document.querySelector('#root').appendChild(cloneItem);
    setTimeout(() => {
     cloneItem.remove();
    },1000)

@keyframes item-to-card-animation{
0%{ 
    opacity:100%;
    transform: scale(1);
}

99%{
   top:-150px;
   left:1150px;
   transform: scale(0.2);
   z-index:100;
}
100%{
   opacity:0%;
}
```

}